# Wordpress ACF - Get taxonomy values

Tags: php, wordpress

I add new custom field to load my Books genres (taxonomy) in to my "writer" page (category).

look at my settings:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0df4qucud7

I need to show the checked genres on my writer page.
Of coure if theres no checked genres the code shows nothing (IF tag).

How can I get the values?

ACF Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the term ID's of the selected genres.
With the ID you can get a field like so `get_field('field_name', 'genre-cat');`
In this situation the `genre-cat` can be replaced for the output of your field with the term IDs (you would have to do this for each term selected, so use the `foreach` statement).

See full documentation from ACF on how to get values from a taxonomy term: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Have you tried getting one single taxonomy first to see if that works. The exact code is in the documentation from ACF. If that doesn't work please show your code and settings so I can check what is going wrong.